# how to get all the records in between a Start Date and End date in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

am a newbie to PowerBi i need some help to filter all the values which come in between the start date and end date. when i tried only one of the filter is working and both the start date and end date are drop down filters i've taken just a dummy data set and practicing it. before implementing it in my project.

this is my dummy data set which i have created in excel. I created a Table based on Employee joining("start date") and Employee resignation date("end date"). The values are a bit unrealistic but i need the logic how we can implement it i need to have both start and end date as Drop Down filters for getting the records between that time frame .

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to compute?

Comment: It sounds like you want Joining Date to be greater than start-date AND Resign Date to be less than end-date.  That's going to require two different filters; one for Joining Date and one for Resign Date.  Also ensure Start Date and Resign Date columns are using the Date datatype in the Modeling Ribbon / tab (access at top of the screen).

Comment: forget abourt the start date and end date i just used it for example  . I just want all the records which are coming in between Joining date and Resign Date

Answer (score 0):

Please use Advanced Filtering in visual filters.

[image]

Comment: @RaviKiran--after entering the dates in Advanced filtering did you click on the apply filter button?

Comment: I tried this solution earlier but it still doesnt work